# Difference between dagbag_import_timeout and dag-file-processor-timeout

Tags: airflow

What is the difference between these variables:

- dagbag_import_timeout: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dagbag-import-timeout
- dag-file-processor-timeout: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-file-processor-timeout

They are both related to parsing a file for DAGs. I guess what is the difference between "importing a python file" and "processing a python file"?